# HTML - Change table cell color based on its content

Tags: html, xml, css, xslt, html-table

I must say I'm an absolute newbie in all this.
I am writing a small xslt presentation file, with a table, and I would like to change the background color of either the cell or the line (either will do, but I would prefer changing only the cell background) depending on the content.

Example:
RATING = "GOOD" "MEDIUM" "BAD"; depending on its value I want the background to be green, yellow or red.

My current table code:

```
<table width="1000" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="table-fill">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">NAME</th>
            <th scope="col">VALUE</th>
            <th scope="col">RATING</th>
            <th scope="col">DESCRIPTION</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <xsl:for-each select="test/criteria">
            <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="@nom" /></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="value" /></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="rating" /></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="descr" /></td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Thank you in advance

--EDIT--
My question has been answered by @Yaakov Ainspan and resolved by @Ruud who gave me the bits of code I was lacking.

It's not a duplicate of "[Is there a CSS selector for elements containing certain text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/is-there-a-css-selector-for-elements-containing-certain-text)" because I didn't need to isolate a element from a string containing more than just my element, just to create classes with the same name as the content of a cell (which was in this case a single word)

Comment: Use classes, then style them by class.

Comment: so you mean i can add a class that will depend on the value of the cell?

Comment: What are the values?

Comment: they are strings, and can be either "GOOD", "MEDIUM" or "BAD"

Comment: by the way, I only wanna change the color of the rating cell

Comment: No, of course not.

Comment: You can change the color of the cell based on its contents using the [jQuery :contains()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.contains/) selector.

Comment: okay, I'm gonna try this and tell you if it works. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS selector for elements containing certain text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/is-there-a-css-selector-for-elements-containing-certain-text)

Comment: @YaakovAinspan it  worked just by creating xsl:attributes with a class name that was the content if the rating cell. No need for the jQuery selector.

Thank you very much for your support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just those three predefined values you could add classes to your stylesheet with the same names:

```css
.GOOD {
    background-color: green;
}
.MEDIUM {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.BAD {
    background-color: red;
}
```

... and add the class attribute to either the row:

```xsl
    <xsl:for-each select="test/criteria">
        <tr>
            <xsl:attribute name="class">
                <xsl:value-of select="rating" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@nom" /></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="value" /></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="rating" /></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="descr" /></td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

... or the cell:

```xsl
    <xsl:for-each select="test/criteria">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@nom" /></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="value" /></td>
            <td>
                <xsl:attribute name="class">
                    <xsl:value-of select="rating" />
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="rating" />
            </td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="descr" /></td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Edit: for better readability you can also add the class this way:

```xsl
    <xsl:for-each select="test/criteria">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@nom" /></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="value" /></td>
            <td class="{rating}"><xsl:value-of select="rating" /></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="descr" /></td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this did what I wanted